# XML-Parser Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, recursion

Let's assume that I have the following XML:

```
<Level>
<Name>Level1</Name>
...
<Level>
<Name>Level2</Name>
...
<Level>
<Name>Level3</Name>
<Level>
<Name>Sublevel1</Name>
<Level>
<Name>Sublevel2</Name>
...
```

How can I access the levels and all the sublevels names and put them in a list. I have written the following code:

```
function getLevel() {
$.get(XmlUrl, function (data) {
var html = "<ol type='i'>";
$(data).find("Level").each(function () {
$(this).children("Level").each(function () {
var list = $(this);
if (list.find("Name")) {
html += "<li>" + $(this).find("Name").text() + "</li>";
} else {
getLevel();
}
});
});
html += "</ol>";
$("#div").append(html);
});
}
```

All I get is this:

```
i.Level1
ii.Level2
iii.Level3Sublevel1Sublevel2
iv.Sublevel1
v.Sublevel2
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Would be easier to provide a fiddle if you provided XML to work with.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/y36qkuLv/1/ - I tried it but it doesn't seem to work :/

Comment: What is the expected output?